# Progress display long field (frame/form)

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

How can i display a long field on screen.

For each cust :
    Display remarks.
End.

The remarks field has 300characters to display. The display statement gives an error that the field is too long to display.

I already tried form and frame definitions. With the width-option this doesn't work.
Now i tried with size 300 by 2 but then it show me 80 chars and scroll bars to see the rest.

How can i display the field completely on the screen without scrolling etc?

Tkx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that a "remarks" field is free form text and that word wrapping is ok.

```
define variable remarks as character no-undo.

remarks = "This is a lot of text.  Hopefully enough to prove the point. I don't really have much to say but I am kind of curious
why all the down votes?  It seems like a reasonable enough question to ask.".

display remarks view-as editor inner-chars 60 inner-lines 10.
```

Comment: You can also do

     "display remarks view-as editor size 60 by 10."

Answer (score 3):

```
   Display Remarks view-as editor size 78 by 15.
```

Where 78 is the width and 15 the number of lines.

If you want just to display and not be able to update:

```
def var remarks as char.

form remarks view-as editor size 10 by 10
with frame f.

remarks:read-only in frame f = true.

update remarks
       with frame f.
```