# How to create multi line text field with vertical scrollbar enabled in openedge progress 4gl?

Tags: char, openedge, progress-4gl

I have a database column called user_notes. This column length is 4000 char. this column having records in multi line.
Now I want to display this column value in progress form. I have tried the method mentioned in the reference URL [Progress display long field (frame/form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999567/progress-display-long-field-frame-form)
But scrollbar not enabled for the field. can anyone advice how to enable vertical scrollbar for long text item field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an editor widget. It does word wrapping and has a vertical scrollbar.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE Editor-1 AS CHARACTER 
     VIEW-AS EDITOR SCROLLBAR-VERTICAL
     SIZE 34 BY 8 NO-UNDO.

Editor-1 = "Test text".


DEFINE VARIABLE wWindow AS WIDGET-HANDLE NO-UNDO.

DEFINE FRAME fFrame
    Editor-1 AT ROW 2 COL 4 NO-LABEL
    WITH 1 DOWN NO-BOX KEEP-TAB-ORDER OVERLAY 
         SIDE-LABELS NO-UNDERLINE THREE-D 
         AT COL 1 ROW 1
         SIZE 40 BY 10.

CREATE WINDOW wWindow ASSIGN
     HEIGHT    = 10
     WIDTH     = 40
     SENSITIVE = yes
     HIDDEN    = no.

DISPLAY Editor-1 WITH FRAME fFrame IN WINDOW wWindow.
ENABLE Editor-1 WITH FRAME fFrame IN WINDOW wWindow.

VIEW wWindow.

WAIT-FOR CLOSE OF THIS-PROCEDURE.
```

Comment: Yes .It is worked for me. Also I want to make this filed as read-only.User should not feed data in this editor .How to make read only editor.

Comment: Add the line `Editor-1:READ-ONLY = TRUE.` somewhere after the frame/window definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Add the READ-ONLY option to disallow data entry.